# Android adb: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: android, adb

Help needed.

PC-Windows 10, Samsung S4 without simcard(connected to same wifi with PC, connected to PC thru USB).

So far. I've **already tried** uncheck/check USBDebugging, unplug/plugin USB, on/off Wifi, just couldn't get connection...What can possibly be wrong?

```
C:\Users\junew>adb devices

List of devices attached
d71ba392        device

C:\Users\junew>adb connect 192.168.0.27

unable to connect to 192.168.0.27:5555: cannot connect to 192.168.0.27:5555: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)(nothing pops up on my screen)

C:\Users\junew>adb kill-server

C:\Users\junew>adb usb

* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully

C:\Users\junew>adb connect 192.168.0.27

unable to connect to 192.168.0.27:5555: cannot connect to 192.168.0.27:5555: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)(Window pops up on Samsung screen, but still unable to connect)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the Galaxy S4 supports adb-over-WiFi. That model is fairly old.

Comment: If not, what to do? There must be a way to deploy an App to an elder phone.

Comment: @JuneWang Did you downvoted my answer? Perhaps tell me why, thanks!

Comment: @navylover I did so, because you copied my answer - while the question is a dupe.

Comment: "There must be a way to deploy an App to an elder phone" -- use the USB cable.

Comment: Actually this is not a duplicate. This question is regarding a specific error that occurs on some devices:
"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)". 
Is it possible to reopen the issue?

Answer (score 9):

1.Connect PC and device with USB cable.
2.Input below commands:

```
  adb kill-server
  adb tcpip 5555
  adb connect YourDeviceIpAddress(e.g 192.168.0.27, you could ensure it via viewing device configuration)
```

Comment: @MartinZeitler I'm in china, may be time delay. I will wait some time to answer question from now on  ^_^, and would you cancel downnote? thank you very much

Comment: Is there a way to connect without connecting via usb first ?

Comment: If we have usb cable there's no need of this method, Very funny requirement : (

Comment: This works but only for some time and the solution is not persistent. After a while the same problem occurs. What could be the reason for that?