# Daemon not started in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, daemon

Please don't mark this as a duplicate question.

When i m trying to run app in emulator or in real device everytime it throws an exception

> Unable to connect to adb. Verify that your localhost entry is pointing to ip4 or ip6 respectively Android

For getting solution i dig google and tried the solution using

> adb tcpip 5555
>
> adb connect 127.0.0.1:5555

But every time it catch the same exception.

> daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
> adb F 05-03 12:32:21  9776  7156 main.cpp:45] cannot open C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\adb.log: Permission denied

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.

Advanced help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found an answer.

There was my silly mistake. While i was set `JAVA_HOME` path by

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_211\bin
```

So just i needed to remove \bin. The correct path is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_211
```

Further i started Android Studio as *Run as Administrator*.

Answer (score 1):

Open command Prompt use following commands

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb devices // it will shows the device id if its connect success
```

if not showing the device restart android studio and mobile then execute the command again it will work

Comment: I did many times. But when i try to above it throw an exception _cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5037: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)_

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922573/android-adb-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-ref

Answer (score 0):

First, try running adb.exe in at the sdk/platform-tools. If it's not working then probably your adb.exe is broken. Then you need to download the sdk again or you can replace the platform-tools folder from some another pc. I also face that problem with Android Studio 3.4.